# How to create and rotate tridimensional matrix in Java or AS3

Tags: java, actionscript-3, matrix, rotation, store

i'm currently working on a personal project and i need to save short ints in a tridimensional array (cube) that allows me to "rotate" the cube and change its orientation (of course i just mean the values inside the matrix). Also i would need to make displacements (translations) of all the values towards one of the axis. Is there a premade way to do this? If it's a java or as3 solution approach it would be nice since i feel more comfortable on one of those technologies.

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: does [this](http://wonderfl.net/c/9ug3) help ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Vector3D](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Vector3D.html) and [Matrix3D](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix3D.html) classes in AS3. Use what you need :)